# MySQL: How do I retrieve n (number of) data from an array?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a messages table.

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | conv_id | body     |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |     haha |
|  2 |       1 |     blabl|
| ...|     ... |    ...   |
|  25|       2 |     hehe |
+----+---------+----------+
```

... = rest of messages with conv_id of 2's or 1's or 3's or n's.

Let's say I have `conv_id = array(2,1)` and I want to obtain 10 messages after matched with an array of ids in `conv_id` so I did

```
select * from `messages` where `conv_id` in (2, 1) order by `created_at` desc limit 10
```

The sql above gave me 10 messages **after** matching both conv_ids and getting **all combined messages**. However, this is **NOT** what I wanted. Instead, I wanted 10 messages **of EACH** conv_id matched.

How do I get 10 messages **of EACH** conv_id matched? No PHP for loop, please. Thank you!

**NOTE** : the array conv_id can easily be extended to include many other values unique to each other, not only 2s or 1s.

---

P.s., **bonus points** for Laravel Eloquent answer! Here are the details :

1. Two models, Conversations and Messages linked by Conversations hasMany Message and Message belongsTo a Conversation.
2. My sql above was translated from `Messages::with('User')->whereIn('conv_id',$conv_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10);`

Comment: One way would be a `UNION` between two queries, one dealing with `1`s, the other `2`s.

Comment: @JaredFarrish right, waiting for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: If only you were using SQL Server or Oracle, a simple partition would work.

Comment: Here's [an in-depth article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) explaining the options. Note that none of the solutions are particularly elegant (all use a subquery, `UNION` and/or variables), because LIMIT in SQL just does not work like this.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like it does what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aefd7a/16 Randomizing it to get something other than the first ten every time would probably be trickier. It's also iffy if it would always return the same 10, so it might work more consistently if the values could only be queried once for the grouping of each value (maybe a `CROSS JOIN` of some kind?).

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks, will take a look soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think Jared is right but if you can add another column to the table, solution would be more efficient. Add a column which indicates message number for each conv_id (earliest will have 1 and the latest will have number of messages conversation have). After that, you can achieve your goal by scanning table twice with `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM messages JOIN
  (SELECT conv_id, MAX(msg_no) FROM messages WHERE conv_id IN (2,1) GROUP BY conv_id) as M 
ON messages.conv_id=M.conv_id HAVING messages.msg_no > M.msg_no-10
```

Comment: Can this query be simplified further? If possible, I need to translate it to Laravel's eloquent functions. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Laravel. However if it is difficult (or not possible? I do not really know) in Laravel, I think it is ok to get your hands dirty sometimes and execute raw SQL statements.

Comment: yup it's possible. I just wanted the codes to look more elegant. :P

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility. Get last conv_ids and their 10th (message)id with a group_concat - substring_index trick and re-join of message-table.

```
SELECT `messages`.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
    conv_id,
    substring_index(
        substring_index(
            group_concat(`messages`.id),
            ',',
            10
        ),
        ',',
        -1
    ) AS lastMessageId
    FROM `messages` 
    WHERE `conv_id` in (2, 1)
    GROUP BY `conv_id`
) AS msub
INNER JOIN `messages` ON `messages`.conv_id = msub.conv_id AND `messages`.id <= msub.lastMessageId
```

Comment: I don't know that the `AND messages.id <= msub.lastMessageId` will work; why not `FIND_IN_SET(messages.id, msub.lastMessageId)`? Also, as an aside, this will return the same 10 entries each time (if that's an issue).

Comment: Thats a performance question but it's surely possible the group_concat result use with a FIND_IN_SET.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: This approach is potentially wrong. I'm trying to validate it and will update it once I reach a conclusion**

Yesterday I just learnt something new about Eloquent relationship from an answer by [deczo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/deczo) in [Getting just the latest value on a joined table with Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24350807/2716927). And I think we can adapt it to your case as well.

What you're essentially trying to do, I put in my view as:

- A Conversation model that has many Messages.
- But I want only 10 latest messages per each conversation. All come eager-loaded.

In Eloquent, I would probably do something along the line of:

```
Conversation::with('messages')->whereIn('conv_id', [1, 2])->get();
```

But two things I note of your question.

- I assume you don't have another table called conversations.
- The code above does not limit to how many messages per conversation.

So I decided that here should be two models, one called Message, another called Conversation.
Both call to the same table, but we will tell Eloquent to use different columns as primary key.
So to get a Conversation model, I added a `distinct()` to my newQuery function, and select only `conv_id` out since that's the only information about a conversation.

So in the end I have this:

**models/Message.php**

```
class Message extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**models/Conversation.php**

```
class Conversation extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $primaryKey = 'conv_id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        return parent::newQuery()
            ->select('conv_id')
            ->distinct();
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Message', 'conv_id')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->take(10);
    }
}
```

Now I can do:

```
Conversation::with('messages')->whereIn('conv_id', [1, 2])->get();
```

which gives me a list of conversations with `conv_id` 1 and 2, along with the 10 latest messages for each of them.

*This is the first time I do something like this. So I code-tested and it works.*

---

**Update:** The code in my answer perform these two queries only (retrieved from DB::getQueryLog()):

```
select distinct `conv_id` from `messages` where `conv_id` in (?, ?);
select * from `messages` where `messages`.`conv_id` in (?, ?) order by `id` desc limit 10;
```

Comment: Btw, what's the newQuery function in Conversations model for and how is it used? I didn't see you using it in your code. Thank you!

Comment: It's from my assumption that "you don't have another table called conversations." The `newQuery()` is what Laravel calls when it starts to construct a query for you. So I append it with select distinct `conv_id` to emulate a conversations table. In case you already have a conversation table just remove my `newQuery()` part totally.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what that raw query looks like.

Comment: @JaredFarrish updated my answer with result from DB::getQueryLog() !

Comment: Hmm wait, something is smelling fishy here. I'll get back with the update.

Comment: If that's really the query that's being used, that would not be any different than the one the OP is getting.

Comment: @JaredFarrish that is true. :( I'm checking my answer plus validating the previous answer that I referred to at the top of my answer too.