# How to make Laravel 4 pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

Hello everyone I'm trying to make pagination in Laravel 4 but my code doesn't work.
I have controller with action:

```
public function getSingleProduct($prodName, $id)
    {               
        $singleProduct = Product::getOne($id);
        $getAllReviews = Review::getAllBelongsToProduct($id);
        $this->layout->content = View::make('products.single')
                                     ->with('reviews', $getAllReviews)
                                     ->with('products', $singleProduct);
    }
```

and I want to paginate getAllReviews (5 per page). I tried like this: 
`$getAllReviews = Review::getAllBelongsToProduct($id)->paginate(5);` but it doesn't work for me. Here is also my Review model

```
public static function getAllBelongsToProduct($id) {
     return self::where('product_id', '=', $id)
                ->join('products', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'products.id')                    
                ->select('reviews.*', 'products.photo')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
}
```

Where I have a mistake?

Comment: `paginate` and `get` can't go together.

Comment: So, how can I get all reviews belongs to one product and paginate this reviews? Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't use this static method. Why do you use that at all? I'd suggest scopes for this, since it's not static in the end - it will instantiate your `Review` model anyway. I will show you how to do it with scope in a sec

Comment: Ok, thanks I've started my adventure with laravel so I'm not a master in this ;p

Comment: Read about query scopes: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that static method on your model use query scope, this will be flexible:

```
// Review model
public function scopeForProduct($query, $id)
{
    $query->where('product_id', $id);
}

public function scopeWithProductPhoto($query)
{
    $query->join('products', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'products.id')                    
      ->select('reviews.*', 'products.photo');
}
```

Then use it:

```
// get all
$reviews = Review::forProduct($id)->withProductPhoto()->latest()->get();

// get paginated
$reviews = Review::forProduct($id)->withProductPhoto()->latest()->paginate(5);
```

`latest` is built-in method for `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`.

If you want to have just a single call in your controller, then chain the above and wrap it in methods on your model.

Comment: Thank you very much so instead of static method should I always use query scope?

Comment: It's not that you should always use query scopes, and never use static methods. However the way I showed you is much more flexible. And you need to know, that every static (or static looking `::`) call to Eloquent Model instantiates it anyway.

Comment: Man can I ask you one more question? How can I get the latest review to each product and display it in page where are all products?

Comment: Use `hasOne` relationship and eager load single review per product, just like in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343738/getting-just-the-latest-value-on-a-joined-table-with-eloquent#answer-24350807

Comment: For me when I did in Product model
`public function latestPrice()

    {

       return $this->hasOne('Review')->latest();

    }

`
It doesnt work for me. I need latest review for each product in  category page. Should I ask new question?

Comment: @Zolax What do you mean?

Comment: I see that you are from Poland have you any communicator? I will explain it.

Comment: catch me in #laravel @freenode

Comment: I can't see you my nick is Zolax.