# Return eloquent relation custom formatted

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation, custom-formatting

I have 2 tables:

```
Services 
id | name | ...

Prices 
id | service_id | day | time | price
```

One service can have many prices (by day in week and time in day).

When I try to get my object and turn it into array this is how it looks now:

```
$service = Service::with('prices')->find(1);

array
  'id' => string '1'
  'name' => string 'Test'
  'prices' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '1'
          'service_id' => string '1'
          'day' => string '1'
          'time' => string '0'
          'price' => string '50.00'
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '2'
          'service_id' => string '1'
          'day' => string '1'
          'time' => string '1'
          'price' => string '50.00'
      ...
```

I would like to get this service object looking like this:

```
array
  'id' => string '1'
  'name' => string 'Test'
  'prices' => 
    array
      1 => array
          '0' => '100.00'
          '1' => '100.00'
          ...
          '23' => '450.00'
      2 => array
          '0' => '100.00'
          '1' => '100.00'
          ...
          '23' => '450.00'
```

In another words, I would like that my relation returns first array that contains days (1-7), and each day is array with time (0-23) in that day.

What is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would have a separate helper class that does the data modification. Assuming your prices model is called Price:

```
class ModelFormatter {

private $pc;

public function __construct(Collection $pricesCollection){
    $this->pc = $pricesCollection;
}

public function toArray(){
    $result = [];

    foreach($this->pc as $item){
         //do checks and build up the $result array
    }

    return $result;
}

}
```

and then

```
$service = Service::with('prices')->find(1);
$prices = $service->prices;
```

`(new ModelFormatter($prices))->toArray();`

Comment: Wouldn't be better to leverage that task to database? To use something like query scope.. With that approach my controller would be cleaner and all the work will be on the db..

Comment: Query scopes are used to specify ...well, the scope of the query. What you're trying to do is get a relationship with an alternative format. So one other option would be to create a separate relationship 'pricesToArray' and somehow modify the relationship so that it returns the data in this format. An example of a modified relationship can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343738/getting-just-the-latest-value-on-a-joined-table-with-eloquent#24350807

Comment: Is there a way to store this new format back to original object $service. Something lik $service->prices  = (new ModelFormatter($service->prices))->toArray();
When I tried to pass that object to javascript or var_dump I see that on prices attribute is original relation from database