# Perform advanced where clause Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would know how to perform an 'Advanced Where'.
I didn't find anything in the documentation that explain what I want.. even there.
(cf: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres).

```
Post::whereHas('international_post_en', function($q) {
       $q->where('is_published', 1);
  })->whereHas('categories', function($q) {
       $q->where('name', 'test-one');
  })->orWhereHas('subcategories', function($q) {
       $q->where('name', 'test-two');
  })->with('categories', 'subtags')
    ->get();
```

My query look like this:

```
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null and (select count(*) from `international_posts_en` where `international_posts_en`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`id` and `is_published` = ?) >= 1 and (select count(*) from `categories` inner join `posts_has_categories` on `categories`.`id` = `posts_has_categories`.`categories_id` where `posts_has_categories`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`id` and `name` = ?) >= 1 or (select count(*) from `subcategories` inner join `posts_has_subcategories` on `subcategories`.`id` = `posts_has_subcategories`.`subcategories_id` where `posts_has_subcategories`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`id` and `name_en` = ?) >= 1
```

But I want my query to look like this:

```
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null and (select count(*) from `international_posts_en` where `international_posts_en`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`id` and `is_published` = ?) >= 1 and [(](select count(*) from `categories` inner join `posts_has_categories` on `categories`.`id` = `posts_has_categories`.`categories_id` where `posts_has_categories`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`id` and `name` = ?) >= 1 or (select count(*) from `subcategories` inner join `posts_has_subcategories` on `subcategories`.`id` = `posts_has_subcategories`.`subcategories_id` where `posts_has_subcategories`.`posts_id` = `posts`.`id` and `name_en` = ?) >= 1[)]
```

(Sorry It is not very readable)

You can see the changes within the brackets.
So, I want the whereHas and the orWhereHas clause to be grouped within parenthesis.

Is it possible with the Laravel Query Builder or should I make a handmade query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post::whereHas('international_post_en', function($q) {
       $q->where('is_published', 1);
  })->where(function ($q) {
     $q->whereHas('categories', function($q) {
       $q->where('name', 'test-one');
     })->orWhereHas('subcategories', function($q) {
       $q->where('name', 'test-two');
     });
  })->with('categories', 'subtags')->get();
```

In fact  this is the very first example on the page you [linked](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres). However that example is pretty inaccurate, since you wouldn't group `and` wheres against `or` where, but the other way around..

Comment: Ok sorry I should have tryied this. I was sure it could not work if it was on relationship.
Thank you it works like I want.

Comment: Just to avoid another post, do you know if i can apply the first() method on an eager loading with a constraint?

Comment: You mean `first` instead of `get` for the whole query? Of course you can.

Comment: Nope,
only on the with method. In my exemple I want to get only the first 'subtags' and the with method return a multidimensional array. So i would apply the first() method only for the this case not for the whole query

Comment: No, it won't work and will lead to unexpected results. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24350807/784588