# Get the first element of a relationship with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I would know if it's possible to retrieve the first element of relation with Eloquent.

This doesn't work:

```
$posts = Post::with(['medias' => function($q) {
    $q->where('type', 'landscape')
      // not working
      ->limit(1);
      // not working
      ->take(1);
      // not working
      ->first();
}])->get();
```

**This is a one-to-many relation.**

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What type of relation is this?

Comment: This is a one-to-many relation

Comment: Wrong link the first time, check again: Then read this [Get latest related model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343738/getting-just-the-latest-value-on-a-joined-table-with-eloquent). Also you can find useful these 2: [n-per-parent](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/) and [count](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/)

Comment: Thank you for this link, it can do the job.
But it looks a bit tricky.
Is there a simplest way to this ?

Comment: Check the link again - first time I gave you wrong one for the `n-per-parent` which is tricky indeed. Now you have the one and only way linked - `hasOne`. There's no other way if you want to eager load this thing.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - You are indeed right. Post it as an answer so that it can be upvoted and accepted. BTW, nice work on your blog there!

Comment: yep post it as an answer

Ok @JarekTkaczyk, thank you again, even if it's not what I expected, less tricky but not really intuitive.

Comment: @KeizerBridge Just upvote the one I linked, no need for duplicating the answers.

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks mate. I'm working on a piece about Eloquent ins and outs exclusively, should be out in a few weeks.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Cool. Keep up the good work. I just subscribed to your feed :D

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Any particular reason your site's RSS feed is truncated? Kind of a bummer :(

Comment: @JosephSilber You mean that only posts' teasers are in the feed, not whole content?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - Correct. You only get the full article by clicking through. Unfortunately that's a deal breaker. I usually read my feeds with no internet access :(