# Eloquent: Get 'max' values from a `hasMany` -> `hasOne` relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have an interesting eloquent challenge and my knowledge is not quite there to work it through, hoping you smart folks can give me some guidance. I have read this: [Getting just the latest value on a joined table with Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343738/getting-just-the-latest-value-on-a-joined-table-with-eloquent) and it is very close to what I want, but I have an extra level of tables in there. 
I have two tables like this:

`User`s have many `Assessment`s. Each `Assessment` `hasOne` `body_fat_testing` (and 4 other `hasOne`s that I need to use as well).

Each `body_fat_testing` table has several columns I'm interested (see below) in.
I'd like to get the "best" result from each "grandchild", per user.

So out of all the assessments, the best `lean_mass`, `body_fat_percentage`, etc
I have this so far:

```
$users = User::with(
    [
        'trainer',
        'firstAssessment.body_fat_testing',
        'firstAssessment.circumference_measurement',
        'firstAssessment.exercise_testing',
        'firstAssessment.overhead_squat_movement_screen',
        'firstAssessment.push_ups_movement_screen',
        'lastAssessment.body_fat_testing',
        'lastAssessment.circumference_measurement',
        'lastAssessment.exercise_testing',
        'lastAssessment.overhead_squat_movement_screen',
        'lastAssessment.push_ups_movement_screen',
    ]
)->find($request->input('user_ids'));
...
(in User.php)

public function lastAssessment()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Assessment')->latest('assessment_date');
}

public function firstAssessment()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Assessment')->orderBy('assessment_date');
}
```

There are about 30 total values I want the "best" of. Any ideas on how to accomplish this without looping through each and every value individually?

`assessment` table:

```
+----+---------+-----+--------+---------------+
| id | user_id | age | weight | assessed_date |
+----+---------+-----+--------+---------------+
|  1 |       7 |  24 |    204 | 2019-10-29    |
+----+---------+-----+--------+---------------+
```

`body_fat_testing` table:

```
+----+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | assessment_id | lean_mass | body_fat_percentage |
+----+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |             1 |    130.97 |               21.10 |
+----+---------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Please add your table structure so that we can have a better idea of how to get the best results

Comment: You can nest your parameters to `with` more deeply. E.g. `lastAssessment.body_fat_testing.whatever`. You should edit your post to include the other relationships as well as what attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: added @Ayrton, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach (it assumes you have models for your three tables and the relationships between them exist):

First, you'll relate your `User` model to your `BodyFatTesting` model, with this:

```
public function bodyFatTestings() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough("App\BodyFatTesting", "App\Assessment");
}
```

Then, you'll create a secondary method `bestBodyFatPercentage` like this:

```
public function bestBodyFatTesting() {
    return $this->bodyFatTestings()->max('body_fat_testing.body_fat_percentage');
}
```

To use it, just get a model in whichever way you prefer and call `bestBodyFatTesting()`.

From there I think you can adapt it to your other "has ones".

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
    public function bestLeanMass()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough('App\BodyFatTesting', 'App\Assessment')
            ->selectRaw('user_id, max(lean_mass) as aggregate')
            ->groupBy('user_id');
    }
```

Not sure which way I like better. The former is a bit easier to understand but creates more methods. This one is harder to understand but fewer methods.

Comment: Having the relationship and the aggregation in separate methods might be better because then you can reuse the relationship for your other aggregates